# R - replacing values in a column with those of another column when other column is not missing

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
    IID sex longitude latitude longitude.1 latitude.1 longitude.2 latitude.2
1234587   0    351500   383500          NA         NA          NA         NA
5145633   1    431340   265505          NA         NA          NA         NA
1305430   1    449500   244900      262500     265500          NA         NA
5012044   0    445600   514300          NA         NA          NA         NA
1234059   1        NA       NA      514300     514300      445500     445520
3087662   0    444500   425200          NA         NA          NA         NA
....
....etc
```

I want to replace the values of longitude with the values of longitude.1 whenever longitude.1 is not missing, and do the same for latitude and latitude.1. I thought this should be easy and tried the following:

```
MyData$longitude[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)] <- MyData$longitude.1
MyData$latitude[!is.na(MyData$latitude.1)] <- MyData$latitude.1
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In MyData$longitude[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)] <- MyData$longitude.1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What did I do wrong?

The outcome should be this:

```
    IID sex longitude latitude longitude.1 latitude.1 longitude.2 latitude.2
1234587   0    351500   383500          NA         NA          NA         NA
5145633   1    431340   265505          NA         NA          NA         NA
1305430   1    262500   265500      262500     265500          NA         NA
5012044   0    445600   514300          NA         NA          NA         NA
1234059   1    514300   514300      514300     514300      445500     445520
3087662   0    444500   425200          NA         NA          NA         NA
....
....etc
```

Comment: the left hand side yeilds two values whereas MyData$longitude.1 yeilds 6. try this: `MyData$longitude[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)] <- MyData$longitude.1[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)]`

Comment: Thank you, that works! If you can give this as an answer, I can give you the credits and points you deserve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyData$longitude[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)]` yields 2 NA whereas `MyData$longitude.1` is all the 6 values. So assignment fails. Get the `longitude.1` that is not NA as well:

```
MyData$longitude[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)] <- MyData$longitude.1[!is.na(MyData$longitude.1)]

MyData$latitude[!is.na(MyData$latitude.1)] <- MyData$latitude.1[!is.na(MyData$latitude.1)]
```